# Can't access to my site form a certain isp after securing .env by htaccess

Tags: laravel

I am working on a live project build on laravel framework. After securing .env file by htaccess, I am facing problem to visit the site from a certain internet connection. **But I can get access to my site by different ISP and Carrier.**
Please help me to figure out the problem

Comment: What is "securing .env"? What have you done?

Comment: What is the actual result you wan't to get?
Why you secured you'r env this way?
Most likely this is php-fpm related problem. Kinda hard to debug.
May be we could find another way?

Comment: @YasinBARAN I just restricted visitor from downloading .env file by typing www.websiteurl.com/ env. Visitor can easily get the env file by just adding . before env. 
And I found the solution from stack overflow. This give the user 403 forbidden warning if they try to download the env file.

Comment: @nojitsi can you please give me some solution about how can i secure my env by not using htaccess file restriction method.

Comment: Simply just run php artisan optimize:clear.